# how to check if timestamp passed is in micro in php

Tags: php, timestamp

How do I check if time stamp passed to the application is in micro? So that I can divide it by 1000. I am looking for solution in PHP.

```
$timestamp = 1554780109;
$_POST['time'] = 1554373624995;

(($timestamp - $_POST['time']) <= 60)
```

Comment: So you obviously get at least 2 formats passed to you. Can you show us 2 examples

Comment: Well if you can make a reasonable assumption of what date range this is supposed to fall in, you can make an educated guess. If not - then you need to make the party passing this to you to explicitly include that information.

Comment: can't you just check the string length?

Comment: @user3174311 That would only work if you expect them to be within a specific range of eachother. For example, `1554810088` is the current *timestamp* (2019-04-09), but if you take that as microseconds instead, we're suddenly in 1970. How would you know if it was a microseconds or in seconds then? If you expect it to be within a specific interval, you'd be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Well,  currently the micro timestamps uses at least 40 bits to their bit set, so, if you shift the bits to right and get any result different than zero then your timestamp is in microseconds. See bellow...

```
function checkMicroTS($timestamp): bool {
    return $timestamp >> 40;
}

var_dump(checkMicroTS(1554808523));    // false
var_dump(checkMicroTS(1554808523480)); // true
```

"But, this code will no longer works if the regular timestamp reaches the 40th bit?"

Yes! But, in this case, we will be at the mark 1099511627776 (02/20/36812 @ 12:36am (UTC)), so i don't think this will be a problem =)

Answer (score 0):

Use [microtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

microtime — Return current Unix timestamp with microseconds

```
$microtime = microtime(true);
```

You can't really tell if data from $_POST is in microtime, please check [Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel) comments.

Comment: I need to check if data from $_POST is in micro as well

Comment: The timestamp `1000000` is 1970-01-12 14:46:40. `1000000000` is 2001-09-09 03:46:40. But what if the inputted values in `$_POST['time']` was microseconds? Then those two dates suddenly change. Your logic does not account for it.

Comment: You can't really tell a timestamp apart from a microtimestamp, unless you predicate a range of which the time is correct.

Comment: @Qirel you are right, i will include a note about that in my answer.